# Determining the code execution order in Eclipse's debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, operator-precedence

For example, I have the following formula;

```
double fooFormula = (-b + Math.sqrt( c ))/ (2*a);
```

in this formula, it is easy to determine the code execution order.

> 1.Math.sqrt(c) will be calculated -> (-b + **Math.sqrt( c )**)/ (2*a)
>
> 2.-b will be added to the result of Math.sqrt(c) -> **(-b + Math.sqrt( c ))**/ (2*a)
>
> 3.The result of 2.step will be divided by 2*a -> **(-b + Math.sqrt( c ))/ (2*a)**

I am currently trying to implement a complex formula but because of the fact that I determined the operation precedence (somewhere in the formula) wrong, the result of the formula is therefore wrong.

I just want to hear if there is any way to let the eclipse show me the which specific operation in the current line (which is highlighted in the debug mode) is executed.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Is this about invoking an expression in a debugger's expressions view? What feature of eclipse's are you using?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I editted my answer. I hope my question is now clearer.

Comment: Your example is wrong; it is not -b+sqrt(c) divided by 2a; it is -b+sqrt(c) divided by 2 and that result multiplied by a.

Comment: Precidence is not the same as execution order. Code execution can be reorganised provided the result is the same.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You are right. I editted my example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Forgive me if I am wrong but isn't code executed based on the operator precedence?

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the left or right half will be calculated first. If a value is a constant, it can be inlined.

Comment: If you use step into in eclipse and allow it to step into java library code (some option or setting somewhere?) it will do so in order of precedence. This may only work for method calls though; untested.

Comment: See also [java operator precedence](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwivyIzj0M7PAhWG2D4KHVrTANEQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2Fnutsandbolts%2Foperators.html&usg=AFQjCNGFtnUz-0mLzF16Lx3f8WlIeoQZeQ&sig2=VRuU8jxmvqUwCUHw6zdTUg)

Comment: @BenKnoble Thank you for your comment. However, the *step into* works only in method calls. In my example, in the processing of the formula, there are some method calls but still, *step into* behaves like the *step over*